# Is AutoCAD knowledge all I needed to be a good designer of electrical drawing

Tags: electrical

Is AutoCAD knowledge all I needed to be a good designer of electrical drawing or do I needed to add other training to equip myself?

Comment: Electrical Drowning? Dym Drafting?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about using application software.

Comment: I assume you'd also need knowledge of electrical.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to volunteer that yes, there is much more it than knowing AutoCAD.

Answer (score 0):

This question really needs more detail as to what your expectations are.

Firstly, AutoCAD is a drawing tool that has often been used for Electrical drafting, but Autodesk now have a product (AutoCAD Electrical) specifically for this.
It is still based on the AutoCAD package and there are many alternatives produced purely for Electrical Drawing, eg. ePlan, SEE Electrical, etc.

It is important that you have a solid understanding of the fundamentals behind Electricity, etc.

The following websites provide a great deal of free knowledge, but you should consider professional training and a qualification to back this up if you wish to embark on a career in the industry;

http://electrical-engineering-portal.com
http://www.electrical-installation.org/enwiki/Main_Page

You should try and grasp the basics and then refer to existing electrical schematics until you begin to understand what you are looking at before attempting to produce your own.

Remember that incorrect design of electrical drawings could end up damaging equipment or injuring/killing personnel working on the equipment.

Comment: Also, don't forget you can refer to: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/ which may be able to provide further information.